# Are there any organisations which approve or manage open science projects?

Tags: open-science

Are there any organisations/foundations/hubs which manages/approve independent open science projects which are accepted and well recognised within mainstream scientific circles?

For instance, what if [the published project doesn't make any sense](http://thatsmathematics.com/blog/archives/102) and its calling it-self the open science project?

In other words, what kind of organisations/community ensure quality of the published data so it's accepted as reliable 'open science' project or anybody can publish anything and call it 'open science project' (for instance publishing open data of [correlation of the number of pirates with global temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster))?

Comment: What sorts of management are you thinking of? Entire management or aspects, such as finance?

Comment: For instance what if the research publishes data/information about theoretical physics (such as cold fusion) which is not accepted by the mainstream science, is the project can be still called open science despite it's against mainstream science, or there will be some pressure to call it differently? Please also note that only [five companies control more than half of academic publishing](http://www.nouvelles.umontreal.ca/udem-news/news/20150610-five-companies-control-more-than-half-of-academic-publishing.html).

Comment: In other words does it need to be approved by some scientific organisation/community so it can use 'science' word in its research data/publication?

Comment: Your comment and question clash "which are accepted and well recognised within mainstream scientific circles", vs "which is not accepted by the mainstream science". It would help to rephrase the question as I and @jaipel have interpreted it similarly differently

Comment: This was just example or to give some different insight, the main question stays the same, are there any communities/organisations which approves such projects, so they can be called open science? Or anybody can publish anything and call it 'open science' in its publication and everybody is happy with it?

Comment: So you mean organisations like the OSI that approves Open Source licences? Not to my knowledge, as what is open is determined by the licences used. There are some definitions such ones on what constitutes open access but even those are not agreed upon by all. So no. And yes, anyone can publish anything and claim it is open science. How open it is depends on the licensing.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: @SimonW I've clarified it a bit more.

Comment: If you think that this thread should be migrated to Academia or another SE site because the OpenScience beta is closing, please edit the list of questions shortlisted for the migration [here](http://meta.openscience.stackexchange.com/questions/73/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, try looking at the [Center for Open Science](http://centerforopenscience.org/) and their study management website, the [Open Science Framework](https://osf.io/).  They primarily deal in psychology and cancer biology studies right now, but I'm sure other areas of science are welcome or will be soon.

Comment: The Center for Open Science are running specific psychology and cancer biology projects (The Reproducibility Projects) that is separate to the service it runs called The Open Science Framework - The OSF is open to all disciplines =)

Answer (score 4):

[**numFocus**](http://numfocus.org/) supports projects producing open source code for science. For example, they provide support to the rOpenSci project in the form of a financial agreement. This allows the project to receive donations and spend monies on project activities etc without having to manage bank accounts and taxes etc.